# Car App htc one m 8

Tags: android, intentfilter, phone-call, mirrorlink

As the HTC ONE M8 is certified for MirrorLink usage, it also has a customized car app, which comes with an activity that allows phone calls while driving.

Is there a way to start this activity from an external application? Is the only way to call this activity if the app or rather that activity has implemented the ACTION_CALL intent?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to start this activity from an external application?

Yes, you can do that with an **[intent filter](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/intent-filter-element.html)**, here´s the information:

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/filters.html

but if you only want to open the application, knowing the application package is enough with:

```
PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
Intent intent = pm.getLaunchIntentForPackage("your.other.app");
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: To do this, the other application has to have the intent filter set and I have to know the package name of the application, right?